# facebook plugin phonegap 3.0

Tags: facebook, cordova

I'm using Phonegap 3.0 and wanted to ask, which facebook plugin actually works.
I wasn't able to get the normal facebook javascript SDK running with phonegap 3.0.

Has anyone else issues with that?

Answer (score 1):

With Phonegap 3.0 the old plugin architecture is deprecated, try this fork: https://github.com/Raffaello/phonegap-facebook-plugin

Comment: almost works, but you have to remove the ".api" from several includes. Then it works.